# Allow users to edit home page from WordPress (home.php problems)

Tags: theme-development, homepage

I am wondering how do you create a home page with a custom design like banners different layout from other pages while allowing users to edit it.

I used to use `home.php` problem is user cannot edit it ... unless they know PHP.

An option will be to create shortcodes for each section of the home page eg. `[banner]`, `[services]` or even an empty tag `[latestBlogPosts]` etc. I dont think its correct.

Whats the way of accomplishing this? A quick "mockup" below of a typical home page

[image]

Things like latest blog post and portfolio are dynamic from wordpress.

Comment: who are the 'users'? is that for a distributable theme? or for multisite?

Comment: @Michel, by users I mean either clients, or users that use the theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do *not* use `home.php` for this purpose. It is a reserved template file name, and is used to display the **Blog Posts Index**.

Your best option is probably to create a `front-page.php` template file, and make the output Widget-based, so that users can modify the display via `Dashboard -> Appearance -> Widgets`.